# If statement never true when inside this mousemove function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a web map with a div called `map2`. As the user moves the mouse in the DIV, the function below is performing math at all times on the cursor location. When a global variable `productAdded` is true, I want a DIV to populate. In my code below, that DIV is within an if statement. However, I verified that the code inside the `if` statement never executes, even when productAdded is true. (I verified this using console.log().

When the app is first started, productAdded is not true but at some point it is true, and it should execute. I have a hunch that the code below only checks if `productAdded` is true or false only one time, and not on each mousemove as I intended it to be.

What am I doing wrong?

The math is left in my example below for completeness, in case I am missing syntax or something.

```
map2.on('mousemove', function(e) {

var str = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.wrap())
var findLon = str.indexOf("lon") + 8;
var lon1 = str.substring(findLon,findLon+7);
var findLat = str.indexOf("lat");
var lat1 = str.substring(findLat+5,findLat+11);
var lon2 = -100.28;
var lat2 = 29.273;
var distFromRadar = distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, "M");
var sliceAngle = 0.5
var elevation = getElevation(sliceAngle, distFromRadar); 

if(window.productAdded==1) // Even when variable true, this code never executes
{
document.getElementById('infoSecond').innerHTML = lon1 + "&deg; " + lat1 + "&deg; &nbsp; &nbsp;" + distFromRadar + "mi  &nbsp; &nbsp;" + elevation + "ft";
} // end if product added

});
```

Comment: It's definitely checking it every time the mouse moves. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Looks like your `window.productAdded==1` condition is not evaluating to `true`.

Comment: any errors in the browser developer tools console? try putting `console.log(window.productAdded)` just before that console.log ... perhaps there's a typo where your code does `productAdded = 1` - e.g. `productadded = 1` or `productAded=1` - typos happen

Comment: hmm, the fact that you need to convert an object to a String (JSON) before extracting values from it suggests there's something messy going on in your code ... very messy - add some console.log's to the mousemove handler to do some debugging

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you. I added console.log(window.productAdded) and it shows undefined. However I can check the variable elsewhere and it is 1. So this is atleast a clue.

Comment: yeah, check where window.productAdded is assigned a value - chances are there's a typo there, or perhaps the code never actually gets there .... you're not dealing with iframes at all, are you?

Comment: @JaromandaX, it looks like the problem was that I declared productSelect in the wrong scope (not globally), but it would have taken a long time to find without your idea a few comments ago. Thank you. Feel free to answer the question for credit.

Comment: `productSelect`?? you mean `productAdded` :p I still don't like that code though ... `JSON.stringify`ing an object to access values in it :p

Comment: Yes, I got my variables confused in my reply. There's quite alot going on in the code. I have to code certain ways as I do not have proper training in JS. I am learning.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to double check and verify that productAdded was global. The code in the question above was in proper syntax and had no runtime errors.